# Combining numeric columns with dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have `int` type columns with dataframe.

I want to make a new column that will hold text representation of the row.

```
df['text'] = df[['project', 'from', 'to', 'score']].apply(lambda x: '_'.join(x), axis=1)
```

I am getting following error `TypeError: ('sequence item 1: expected string or Unicode, int found', u'occurred at index 0')`

How I can add `casting to string` with my text generation function ?

Answer (score 2):

Try cast to `str` by [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html):

```
df['text'] = df[['project', 'from', 'to', 'score']]
                .apply(lambda x: '_'.join(x.astype(str)), axis=1)
```

Or:

```
df['text'] = df[['project', 'from', 'to', 'score']]
                 .astype(str)
                 .apply(lambda x: '_'.join(x), axis=1)
```